# Parametric Equations for the Coordinates of an Orbit as a Function of Time

Tags: orbital-motion

We are given velocity, direction of velocity, distance between the two bodies and the mass of massive body. The effect of the mass of the orbiting body can be ignored.

I am looking for parametric equations with inputs of velocity, angle, distance, mass and time which return the 2D coordinates of the orbiting body, in the form:

\begin{align}
x& = f_x(v,a,d,M,t) \\
y& = f_y(v,a,d,M,t)
\end{align}
I have had my own attempt.

let $A$ = semi-major axis,
$$
A = \left(\frac{v^2}{GM} + \frac2d\right)^{-1}
$$

let $B$ = semi-minor axis,
$$
B = \cos(a) v r\sqrt{\frac{\vert A\vert}{GM}}
$$

where $G$ = gravitational constant

\begin{align}
x &= A \sin(t)\cos(a) - B\cos(t)\sin(a)\\
y &= A\sin(t)\sin(a) + B\cos(t)\cos(a)
\end{align}
It doesn't work. For example, it is not circular when $v = \sqrt{GM/d}$

Do such equations exist?

Comment: I've transcribed your text into equations, hopefully I've done it right. In the future, see [the Notation page for help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Also, I think [this may be related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99094/)

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I will definitely try to process the information in the post you linked.

Comment: This approach won't work, even after correcting for the errors in your expression for A and B.